# How to get a matrix from all the attributes of a list with their value's in R

Tags: xml, r

I have a list in R and I want a matrix with all the attributes and their value's of that list.

```
data.list$A$value = 1
data.list$B$value = 2
data.list$C$value = 3
```

The matrix must look like:
A  B  C
1  2  3
ect.
I though of this code, but this doesn't work:

```
attributes(data.list)$value
```

What is the right code get this matrix?

Comment: have you tried to convert it to a data.frame() ???

Comment: library (plyr)
df <- ldply (data.list, data.frame)

This does't give me the preferred matrix/table

Comment: Can you provide with a replicable example of how you load the list?, and btw, I meant something like a<-data.frame(list)

Comment: data.list <- xmlToList(data, addAttributes = TRUE, simplify = FALSE)

it's from a XML file to a list. I couldn't make a data.frame from it